# If you could only monitor 10 SQL Server 2005 counters, what would they be?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Yes, this is rather subjective, but I am doing research on that matter and am curious to see if others have come to the same conclusions that I have.  So, I ask, if you could only monitor 10 SQL Server 2005 counters, what would they be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Page Life Expectancy (prefer over Buffer Cache Hit Ratio)

Memory Pages/sec

% Processor Time

SQL Server Memory Grants Pending (not Outstanding)

Physical Disk Avg Disk Sec/Read

Physical Disk Avg Disk Sec/Write (prefer over Queue Length, though both work OK)

SQL Server Agent Failed Jobs

SQL Server Lock Waits Avg Wait Time

Answer (score 3):

Are these SQL Server specific counters or SQL Server Machine Counters?  If they are machine wide counters then I recommend these:

- SQLServer: Memory Manager: Memory Grants Outstanding
- SQLServer: General Statistics:Logins/Sec, Logouts/Sec, User Connections
- Memory: Available Bytes
- Memory: Pages/Sec
- Paging File: % Usage
- PhysicalDisk: Avg. Disk Queue Length
- Processor: % Processor Time

Comment: What about SQLServer:BufferManager/BufferCacheHitRatio?  That one is important too - and it looks like you've only got 9 listed there :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using PAL (http://pal.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=28708) Performance Analysis of Logs.  It makes the task of reviewing perform logs much easier.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for.  Thanks for the post though.